# custom newsletter plugin development in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Hi i am implementing newsletter plugin basic functionality comparing to the contact us plugin.But facing one problem while sending an email.

Actual problem is in my code i am having Name,Email,Message and Subject but from the below i need to remove Name and Message.Instead of message i need to display default message which includes Email address as well.If i remove Name and Message and sending mail then it is getting as unexpected error.Here is the code for that.

```
function html_form_code() {
echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
echo '<p>';
echo 'Your Name (required) <br/>';
echo '<input type="text" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
echo '</p>';
echo '<p>';
echo 'Your Email (required) <br/>';
echo '<input type="email" name="cf-email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
echo '</p>';
echo '<p class="subjectline" style="display:none;">';
echo 'Subject (required) <br/>';
echo '<input type="text" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value=" Subscription List" size="40" />';
echo '</p>';
echo '<p>';
echo 'Your Message (required) <br/>';
echo '<textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="cf-message">' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';
echo '</p>';
echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Sign Up"></p>';
echo '</form>';
}

function deliver_mail() {

// if the submit button is clicked, send the email
if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

    // sanitize form values
    $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-name"] );
    $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["cf-email"] );
    $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["cf-subject"] );
    $message = esc_textarea( $_POST["cf-message"] );

    // get the blog administrator's email address
    $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

    $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

    // If email has been process for sending, display a success message
    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me, expect a response soon.</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove Name: go this way, just change your line to this one.

```
$headers = "From: <$email>" . "\r\n";
```

This way you name will not be appended to the email.

You can add your custom message this way, instead of getting value from the form.

```
$message = "your custom message goes here";
```

That way it will send always your provided string rather than taking it from form. Hope it solves your issue, if you need any further assistance let me know.

Comment: But how to remove name field if i am  removing name field then the mail functionality is not working

Comment: can you also provide me code without name field so that I can figure out what's causing the issue ?

Comment: I got it, you should not remove your $name variable, because that's being used inside headers. So, just remove your name variable from headers line, for details check my updated solution.

Comment: check updated solution now, if you remove $name variable, then its being used in header and once it gets empty it throws you to no email sent message. Just go this way As I mentioned above and it will solve your issue by now.

Comment: Removed $name from header but facing one issue is in the email getting as Wordpress<email@gmail.com> i need to remove that wordpress as well from address

Comment: And one more issue is once the data is filled and submitted the data is not getting cleared until we refresh the page.THe data should be automatically cleared once we fill the form and submitted

Comment: that's due to wp_mail function ... you can play with it to remove any of your data as you want ... or can use default php mail function ... thanks

Comment: @Akramulhaq i am not getting you what you are saying

Comment: just use wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'The subject', 'The message' ); this thing and note what its sending to you ..... put your own email in place of this email given ...

Comment: and i need to add logo as well while sending confirmation mail at the bottom

Comment: Success Message has been completed.How to add logo while sending email can you please update that one it will be very helpful for me

Comment: How to add logo to email while sending

Comment: you can add another option like shown below: wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachment ) ... in this case $attachment is your logo ... you can send any file as attachment .... thanks

Comment: Actually i dont want the attachments at the end i need to add logo after message.

Comment: then go this way $message .= '<img src="your image path here">'; add this line after your $message = esc_textarea( $_POST["cf-message"] ); line and provide your own image path in place of image src above ... it will work fine for you ... :)

Comment: Last doubt while sending confirmation mail i am getting WordPress <wordpress@qa.website.com> i need to remove these wordpress and need to add my website name how to do that where can i change that wordpress

Comment: what is name of your website ? is it wordpress ? that may be due to that ?

Comment: No it is not wordpress but from where it is getting i am not able to understand can you please suggest where can i change that

Comment: $headers = get_option( 'admin_email' ); in headers i have given like this so it is getting the mail like that.I need to give from address as ashalatha@gmail.com with my name instead of wordpress

Comment: yes, that's the point to do it ... that's good that finally you have done with ... have good time and keep good work up :)